# $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ implies $\Delta u\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary.

Is it true that if $u  \in H^1(\Omega)$, then $\Delta u \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, user86544, people here use English to ask and answer questions. It is possible that your question will end up like the previous two of yours, my suggestion is translating it into English first.

Comment: QuE es "bien regular"?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I disagree. If the OP is not certain of how to formulate the problem in English, rather than attempting a translation by themselves or using an automatic service, they may post the question in their native language, and users here may translate it more accurately. I for one do not recall ever encountering in Spanish the term "bien regular" (well, I'm old and forgetful), I doubt an automatic translation would suggest the technical term.

Comment: *abierto* means *open*, and *acotado* means *bounded*. And *bien* is something like *well-*.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Google translate detecting language gives "open and bounded" for "abierto y acotado". Also the problem with OP is that he showed no effort in formulating the question, nor his own effort, please refer to his two previous questions.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Whether there was effort or not is a separate matter. (I agree a better thought out phrasing of the question would be desirable.) Again, the issue is the meaning of "bien regular", not of anything else in the post. "Smooth" is probably a good translation, if we take it to mean (locally) $C^\infty$. Still, we could be missing something there.

Comment: What is your definition of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First check that the Laplacian operator on $u$ corresponds to multiplication of the Fourier transform $\hat u$ by ${\xi_1}^2+\dots+{\xi_n}^2$ (up to a sign that depends on the convention in the definition of $\Delta$). Then compare that with the definition of the Sobolev spaces in terms of Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 2):

If $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ then, by definition, $\nabla u\in L^2(\Omega)^n$. On the othe hand, by definition, we have that $$\tag{1}\langle \Delta u,v\rangle=-\langle\nabla u,\nabla v\rangle, \ \forall \ v\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$$

To conclude, you have to use $(1)$, the fact that $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and the fact that $\nabla u\in L^2(\Omega)^n$. Can you do this?

Remark: Also, I let for you to give the correct meaning of the expression in $(1)$.

Comment: In this answer, is $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ assumed to be the dual of $H^1(\Omega)$ or $H^1_0(\Omega)$?